# Can't change backgroundcolor of navbar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

In my iOS app, I'm using REFRostedViewController (https://github.com/romaonthego/REFrostedViewController) without a storyboard. It's working fine. However, I don't want the navigation bar to be blurred and so I set out to change this. I'm not having any luck though.

I tried setting `self.navigationController.navigationbar.background = [UIColor blueColor]` in just about any view. That makes the blur blueish.

I've been trying to fix this for about two days. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following `code` in where you are `initializing` your `NavigationController`

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{
                                                            NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blueColor],

                                                            }];
```

Comment: A small notice if someone reading the answer doesn't know: this works across all app, not only this given navigation bar.

Comment: This just changes the color of text.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the navigation bar to be transparent then? If you want it to have full alpha try:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything. My guess is that `REFrostedViewController` does something to the navbar as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

`[navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];` //Red as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting below property of navigaiton nar

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor yourColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```